# how to pass values to function from alert button in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

i am trying to call and pass values to my function from Alert Button "Yes", but its not working , function is not receiving values and giving error undefined when i used function values. here is my code

```
    const sendemail = async ({ email, hash, password }) => {
        console.log(email); //getting Error here undefined email
    }
      Alert.alert(
                  "Account is not activated",
                  "kindly check your email box and verify your account.Do you want to Resend Verification Email ?",
                  [
                    {
                      text: "Yes",
                      onPress: () =>
                        this.sendemail(
                          email,
                         hash,
                          password
                        ),
                    },
                    {
                      text: "No",
                      // onPress: () => console.log("No"),
                    },
                  ]
                );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the sendemail call you are not passing an object, you are passing three parameters. And then you are trying to destructure an object in the method.
Try this: (I've only removed the destructuring in the method definition)

```
const sendemail = async ( email, hash, password ) => {
        console.log(email); 
    }
      Alert.alert(
                  "Account is not activated",
                  "kindly check your email box and verify your account.Do you want to Resend Verification Email ?",
                  [
                    {
                      text: "Yes",
                      onPress: () =>
                        this.sendemail(
                          email,
                         hash,
                          password
                        ),
                    },
                    {
                      text: "No",
                      // onPress: () => console.log("No"),
                    },
                  ]
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try eliminating

"() =>" from the Yes's onPress method, if not try adding the parameters in the "() =>" so it would look something like

onPress: (e, h, p) =>
this.sendemail(
e,
h,
p
),